# How to filter categories by tag filter properly?

Tags: wordpress, filter, tags, categories

I use category pages for my Wordpress website, where the posts assigned to the respective category are listed as usual. I now want to give visitors the ability to filter the list of posts within a category by tags (for example they shall be able to show only posts with the tag "shirts" within the clothing-category).

This works great with /?tag=example added to the category URL. The problem: If a tag is specified here that does not exist or if no article has this specific tag, the specific category page will be displayed, just without any posts - not a good user experience.

Instead I want to display the text "No articles exist in this category for this tag".

How can I achieve this?

Regards

Comment: Nobody can help?

Comment: Hello? Anybody there?